# RK3 order of convergence problem

Tags: numerical-methods

Hi I am trying to figure out the order of convergence for RK3 by plotting the solution for different step sizes ($N$) as a function of the step size.
This is my code. What am I doing wrong? I get 2 when it is supposed to be 3.

```
%FUNCTION`
function res = RK4(h, u0, f)

    k1 = f(u0);
    k2 = f(u0 + h*k1);
    k3 = f(u0 + h*k1/4 + h*k2/4);

    res = u0 + (k1 + k2 + 4*k3)*h/6;

end
% MAIN PROGRAM
close all, clear all, clc
hold on
format long
eps = 1;
t0 = 0;
tInt = 1;
u0 = [1 0]';
uEnd = [];
H = [];

f = @(u)[u(2); -eps*(u(1)^2 - 1)*u(2) - u(1)]; %vector function

for N = [10 20 40 80 160 320]
    u = u0; 
    h = tInt/N;
    H = [H h];
    for t = t0+h:h:tInt

        u = RK4(h, u, f);

    end
    uEnd = [uEnd u(1)];
end
eN = abs(uEnd - uEnd(end)); %ungefÃ¤r un - u(1)
loglog(H, eN)
loglog(H, H.^3,'r')
order = log(  (eN(end-3)-eN(end-2))/(eN(end-2)-eN(end-1))  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from everything said below about getting the integration interval as exact as possible:

-> Your formula for the order exponent is a bit off.

The fraction inside the logarithm is $2^p$ (by the way, the would still be correct if you were using `uEnd` instead of the `eN` array). However, you need to use the binary logarithm, not the natural. Thus

```
p = log2(.../...) = log(.../...)/log(2)
```

Note that $\ln(2^3)=2.07944154168…$ which probably lead to your question.

---

Try to integrate $u'=1$ to see if you actually reach the accurate interval end.

In general, either

- perform the given number of steps by iteration over an integer counter

  ```
  h = (t1-t0)/N
  for i = 0 to N-1 do
      u = RK_step(f,t0+i*h,u,h)
  end
  ```

or

- integrate the time and perform a final step using the remaining time

  ```
  t=t0
  while t +1.1*h < t1
      u = RK_step(f,t,u,h)
      t=t+h
  end
  h = t1 - t
  u = RK_step(f,t,u,h)
  ```